# Socket not emit messages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, sockets

I've had a problem with receiving message from client to server with using React and ExpressJS. After launch `sendMessage` function on client side I want to send to server my message, but, I don't know why this message is not being received by my server and `io.on("message", (message) => {` is not launched with his console.log :/

Here is my code

Server side:
index.ts

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
export const socketIo = socket(server);
```

socket.ts

```
export const socket = (httpServer: any) => {
    const io = new Server(httpServer, { cors: { origin: "http://localhost:5000" } });

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        console.log("Socket connected!")
        socket.emit('connection', null);
    });

    io.on("message", (message) => {
        console.log("NEW MESSAGE: ", message)
    })
}
```

Client side:
App.tsx

```
const SOCKET_SERVER = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";

export const socket = socketClient(SOCKET_SERVER);
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('CONNECTED WITH BACKEND SOCKET')
})
```

Chat.tsx

```
  const sendMessage = () => {
    const message = form.getFieldsValue()["typedMessage"];

    socket.emit("message", message);
    
    form.resetFields();
  };
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Socket connected!")
    socket.emit('connection', null);
});

io.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log("NEW MESSAGE: ", message)
})
```

The "connection" is triggered on the server listener and provides a connected socket. The socket is then used to receive messages. This means receiving messages must be done on `socket`, not on the listener `io`:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Socket connected!")
    socket.emit('connection', null);

    socket.on("message", (message) => {
        console.log("NEW MESSAGE: ", message)
    });
});
```

Comment: on client side is this same logic that i have to listen inside `socket.on('connect', () => {` for every emit/on

Comment: @BokuNoHeeeero: on the client side `socket` is already the connected socket, there is no server socket at the client side.